# Is it possible to get a user to "pre-order" for a subscription on an iOS app and then "turn on" the subscription at a later date?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are building an iOS app and offer have two subscription plans: a monthly & a yearly.

We want to let our users pick a plan now to essentially "pre-order" their subscription. At a later date (which is TBD), we want to "turn on" that subscription. Note that we dont want to start charging them until we turn it on down the line.

This is slightly different from offering something like a 1 month free trial, because we aren't specifying a set date for when their subscription will begin (we are still building parts of our beta and want to get pre-orders now before launching it).

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the native subscriptions proposed by Apple, no it's not possible.